# how to login to azure getting the token from a file

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline with which I want to get access to Azure Devops to to trigger some pipelines, I have follow the the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) and if I set it to get the token in the first way such as `$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = 'xxxxxxxxxx` it works fine but if I try to use the cat method `cat my_pat_token.txt | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/contoso/` I get this error `powershell.exe : ERROR: TF400813: The user '' is not authorized to access this resource.`

I have used this same method in another local Jenkins I have and it works fine, the .txt file is within the workspace and if I do `cat my_pat_token.txt` I get the token value, but yet it does not seem to work. This is the whole pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers{
        cron("""H 5 * * *
            H 18 * * 5""")
    }
    stages {
        stage('azure') {
            steps {
                script{          
                        powershell '''                      
                        cat my_pat_token.txt | az devops login
                        az devops configure --defaults organization=<myorganization>    
                        az devops configure --defaults project=Project1
                        az pipelines build queue --definition-id 343 --variables "var1=value" "var2=value"                                    
                    '''                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this pipeline works smooth and fine:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers{
        cron("""H 5 * * *
            H 18 * * 5""")
    }
    stages {
        stage('azure') {
            steps {
                script{          
                        powershell '''                      
                        $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = 'sometoken'
                        az devops configure --defaults organization=<myorganization>    
                        az devops configure --defaults project=Project1
                        az pipelines build queue --definition-id 343 --variables "var1=value" "var2=value"                                    
                    '''                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `cat my_pat_token.txt | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/contoso/`, I don't see the `--organization` in your command.

Comment: I get the same error either way, and on my local Jenkins it works without the `--organization`, but I tried both ways with the same result anyways